# How to get information from Wordpress API when use iThemes Security Pro Plugin

Tags: wordpress

I'm using iThemes Security Pro Plugin to restrict access to REST API.
Then, based on their doc, I create an application password to allow my mobile get information from my website via REST API. But I dont know how to use application password from iThemes Security Pro to get these informations.

Below is the response from WP REST API when I try access this url: "https://creepypastaholics.com/index.php/wp-json/wp/v2/posts"

{

"code": "itsec_rest_api_access_restricted",
"message": "You do not have sufficient permission to access this endpoint. Access to REST API requests is restricted by iThemes Security settings.",
"data": null

}

How can I use "Application Password" to get information from WP REST API?

Comment: I need support on this also.